# 開発のために接続された iPhone と mac の間で LAN を構築したい

Tags: ios, macos, network

iOS アプリと、それと通信を行う api サーバーの開発を mac でしています。普段はシミュレーターベースの開発で、その際には localhost で立てた api サーバーを参照させていたので、問題なく動いていました。実機での挙動を確認したくなったので、 iPhone を mac に接続して、アプリを動かそうとしたときに、 api を取得するホストは、 localhost ではなく、 mac のものを指定する必要があることに気がつきました。

mac の IP を指定するにあたって、今 mac がつながっている LAN に、 iPhone も接続させて、プライベートIP をアプリケーション上で指定し、かつ api サーバーを 0.0.0.0 でバインドすれば、ひとまず動くことは確認したのですが、たとえばシェアオフィスであったり、カフェで作業する場合などには、この方法はあまりとりたくないと考えました。

#### 質問:

- mac から、動作確認のために iPhone に対してアプリをデプロイする際に、 LAN を構築して、 iPhone からしかアクセスできないようなネットワークを構築できたりなどしないでしょうか。(ないし、接続されている iPhone で、ホストの mac を解決可能な形で指定する方法などはありますか?)

Answer (score -1):

方法は2つ考えられます。
方法1:Macに割り当てられているIPアドレスをターミナルアプリから「ifconfig」で調べて、都度iOSのアプリのソースをそのIPアドレスに変更する方法
方法2:Macをインターネット共有を利用してWifiルーター化して接続する方法

**方法1**
1)任意のカフェやシェアオフィスに接続します。
2)Macからターミナルアプリを起動し、「ifconfig | grep inet」コマンドを実行します
3)Macが所持しているIPアドレスの一覧が出ますので、そのIPアドレスをiOSアプリのAPIサーバーのIPアドレスに指定します。

IPアドレスは複数表示されることが多いですが、大体192.168.で始まるものか10.で始まるものが使うべきIPアドレスだと思います。

**方法2**
1)任意のカフェやシェアオフィスに接続します。
2)次のURL「http://omomukibukai.com/mac-router/」を参考にMacをWifiルーター化します
　細かい手順を以下に引用します。

> 1.システム環境設定を選択 
>   2.共有(３段目の右端)を選択く
>   3.画面左側のサービス一覧から、インターネット共有を選択
>   4.画面右側のポート一覧から、WI-FIを選択し、枠の下のWF-FIオプションを選択。
>   5.ネットワーク名、チャンネル、セキュリティ、パスワードを設定する。
>   6.最後に、「共有」のサービス一覧のインターネット共有にチェックを入れて終わり。

3)ここで作成したWifiにiPhone端末で接続します。(自動認識しないときは手動設定してください)
4)接続に成功すれば、「設定アプリ」>「Wi-Fi」>「接続されているwifi」をタップし、そこに表示されるルーターのIPアドレスがMacのアドレスになるはずです。
5)ルータのIPアドレスをiOSアプリのAPIサーバーのアドレスに設定します。

余談ですが、Mac上でAPIサーバーを立てず、どこかサーバーを借りてAPIサーバーにした方が、どこからでも接続できていいかもしれません

以上、いかがでしょうか？

Comment: 方法の2番目について、どうやら、 mac がシェアオフィスなどの共有 Wifi につながっている状態では、 mac を Wifi ルータ化させることはできない様子です。できるのは、 mac の Wifi 接続を USB ポートを通じて iPhone からも利用する、の様子ですが、だったら素直に iPhone を オフィスの Wifi につないでしまえばよさそうだ、と思っている状態です。